# android c2dm registration Id fails

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-c2dm

I am working on google's C2DM and have a program on the android emulator trying to get registration ID. But I get following errors:

DEBUG/GoogleLoginService(171): onBind: Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService }

WARN/GoogleLoginService(171): Device has no accounts: sending Intent { act=com.google.android.gsf.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_MISSING }

ERROR/GTalkService(171): asyncFetch: no username

DEBUG/C2DMRegistrar(171): [C2DMRegistrar.20] AuthTokenCallback: account missing

Answer (score 14):

Your device needs to have at least one Google account set up under Settings/Accounts for C2DM to work.

Comment: When I do this, it complains about not having the correct username/password combination. I'm sure I entered my details correctly...

Comment: Tried using a fresh Google account and it worked perfectly. I'm guessing it didn't like the fact that I had already associated my original Google account with another device. Still, it's an unhelpful error message.

Answer (score 2):

This is Because your device is not in Sync with the Google
Go to Settings and add account enter Your Google account username and Password.
Hope this Works..